# how do i configure and use django-allauth app for my application

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have installed the django-allauth application and started using it but i am facing problems like:
1) confused on urls.py configuration.
2) shows me no social apps registered if i go onto login via social apps like facebook
3) if at all i login sometimes then it directs me to a url having profile and nothing matched says.
please help,
thanks.

the app is called as:" https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth"

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem you have to log in to admin site, and add **socialapp** under **Social apps**.

So, for facebook you will add your app's secret id and key.